# Split String Column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
acctcode         primekey          groupby    <--- columns

 WDS                1              'NULL'     <--- values (varchar)       
 FDS                2              'NULL'
 IRN                3              'NULL'
 SUM                4              1,2,3
 STL                5              'NULL'
 WTR                6              'NULL'
 SUM2               7               5,6
```

I want to split string `groupby` column where values are **NOT EQUAL** to `'NULL'`
and save it to another table which will look like this:

```
acctcode          primekey         groupby
 SUM                 4                1
 SUM                 4                2
 SUM                 4                3
 SUM2                7                5
 SUM2                7                6
```

here is my split string code:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT primekey = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

here is the code I use to call the function:

```
SELECT acctcode,(SELECT * FROM SplitStrings(groupby,','))as prime 
INTO Chadtblsum
FROM Chadothercharges WHERE acctcode = acctcode
```

The code above gives me this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

The above error happens since your subquery in the `SELECT` returns more than one row. Try executing this:

```
SELECT * FROM SplitStrings('1,2,3',',') x
```

You'll see that it'll return 3 rows, one for each item.

In order to fix this, you have to use `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46423/3/0)

```
SELECT 
    c.acctcode,
    x.primekey AS prime
INTO Chadtblsum
FROM Chadothercharges c
CROSS APPLY SplitStrings(c.groupby,',') x
WHERE groupby <> 'NULL'
```

Comment: Thank you @Felix Pamittan - I used your code and adjust it a little bit to get the specific data i needed: `SELECT 
    c.acctcode,
    x.primekey AS prime
INTO Chadtblsum
FROM Chadothercharges c
CROSS APPLY SplitStrings_XML(c.groupby,',') x
WHERE acctcode = acctcode
AND groupby <> 'NULL'
ORDER BY primekey
`

Comment: No problem. Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @Table1 TABLE 
    ([acctcode] varchar(4), [primekey] int, [groupby] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([acctcode], [primekey], [groupby])
VALUES
    ('WDS', 1, NULL),
    ('FDS', 2, NULL),
    ('IRN', 3, NULL),
    ('SUM', 4, '1,2,3'),
    ('STL', 5, NULL),
    ('WTR', 6, NULL),
    ('SUM2', 7, '5,6')
;

select   [acctcode], [primekey],
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SubColour  
     FROM  (SELECT [acctcode], [primekey],
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([groupby], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
         FROM  @Table1) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```